# Resolving a warning in verilog: read after blocking assignment in same process

Tags: verilog, warnings, system-verilog

I've this code which is throwing some warning messages which I'm trying to resolve.

```
module someModuleName(...)
...
...
reg [3:0] i;
wire [3:0] onstate_count;
wire [3:0] ack_count;
reg [3:0] j;
bit switchState;
always @(*) begin :EVAL_ACK 
switchState = 1'b0;
for (i = 0; i < onstate_count; i = i+1) begin 
   if (onStateControls[i] == 1'b1) begin 
     switchState = 1'b1;
   end 
end 

for (j = 0; j < ack_count; j = j+1) begin 
    if (ack_expression_type[j] == 1'b0) begin 
        if (switchState) begin 
            ack[j] = ack_logic_value[j]; 
        end else begin 
            ack[j] = !ack_logic_value[j]; 
        end 
    end else begin 
        ack[j] = ack_logic_value[j]; 
    end 
end 
end

endmodule
```

The warning mesage I'm getting is:

```
Warning-[SM_TPL] Transaction path loss after synthesis
In module 'someModuleName', transaction path through signal 'i' will be
lost after synthesis due to read after blocking assignment in same process.
-
Warning-[SM_TPL] Transaction path loss after synthesis
In module 'someModuleName', transaction path through signal 'switchState' will be
lost after synthesis due to read after blocking assignment in same process.
-
Warning-[SM_TPL] Transaction path loss after synthesis
In module 'someModuleName', transaction path through signal 'j' will be
lost after synthesis due to read after blocking assignment in same process.
```

I tried making i, j as integer and genvar but no effect, I'm new to verilog and don't know how to resolve this warning.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Synthesizers require loops to static unroll.
A loop must be able to static unroll to be synthesizable.

Using a snip it from your original code:

```
switchState = 1'b0;
for (i = 0; i < onstate_count; i = i+1) begin // <-- onstate_count is not a compile time constant, therefore cannot static unroll
  if (onStateControls[i] == 1'b1) begin
    switchState = 1'b1;
  end
end
```

The equivalent synthesizer friendly version would be:

```
switchState = 1'b0;
for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i+1) begin // <-- loop is static
  if (i < onstate_count) begin     // <-- condition check
    if (onStateControls[i] == 1'b1) begin
      switchState = 1'b1;
    end
  end
end
```

A similar change needs to be made to `for (j = 0; j < ack_count; j = j+1)`. The `ack` also needs to be assigned a value for indexes greater than `ack_count` or it will infer a latches; and most FPGA synthesizers do not support latches.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. Also are `onstate_count` and `ack_count` variables constants?

```
module someModuleName(...)
...
... 
genvar i,j;
wire [3:0] onstate_count;
wire [3:0] ack_count;

bit switchState; 

generate
  for (i = 0; i < onstate_count; i = i+1) begin
   always @(*) begin :EVAL_ACK  
    switchState = 1'b0;
 
     if (onStateControls[i] == 1'b1) begin 
       switchState = 1'b1;
     end 
    end 
   end
endgenerate



generate
   for (j = 0; j < ack_count; j = j+1) begin
     always @(*) begin
            if (ack_expression_type[j] == 1'b0) begin 
                if (switchState) begin 
                    ack[j] = ack_logic_value[j]; 
                end else begin 
                    ack[j] = !ack_logic_value[j]; 
                end 
            end else begin 
                ack[j] = ack_logic_value[j]; 
            end 
        end 
        end
    endgenerate

    endmodule
```

Comment: I declared the variable in the for loop and it works: for(int i=0; i<onstate_count; i = i+1).
The other problem I'm facing is I've a variable "logic [1:0] internalSaveSense = 2'b00;", here I'm using blocking assignment and in some other process I'm using non-blocking assignment for the same variable "internalSaveSense <= 1'b0;". This is giving me a warning "Blocking and Non Blocking Assignments in different Processes", How can I resolve this?

Comment: This is not legal. You will run into multi-driver issue. Always drive registers using one process block.